# mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

Tags: php, parameters, null

The line causing the error is this one...

```
mysql_close($con);
```

Here is the entirety of the code...

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM medicos");


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '.....';
    }



    mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: You're mixing mysql and mysqli...you either have to use all mysql or all mysqli

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The line `mysql_close($con);` must be changed to `mysqli_close($con);`

You cannot interchangeably use `mysql` and `mysqli` functions, for example:

`mysqli_connect` requires use of `mysqli_close`

*- likewise -*

`mysql_connect` requires use of `mysql_close`