# Errors while connecting with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting below errors while connecting with MySQL.

> Warning: mysql_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 64
>
> Warning: mysql_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=9080 in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 64
>
> Warning: mysql_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 64
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 64

Comment: you use any loop in register.php page

Comment: Show us the code that produces the error

Comment: You should upgrade to mysqli or PDO.. mysql_* functions are deprecated

Comment: thank you for reply

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MySQL+server+has+gone+away

Comment: I didnt use any loop in register.php

Answer (score 0):

And Change in php.ini `(C:\xampp\php\php.ini)`

```
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
max_allowed_packet = 200M (in my.ini)
```

Comment: i added above lines in php.ini but  still iam getting errors.and one more error added to that.     Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 76

Comment: did you restart the xampp

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these line in your php.ini file

```
`max_execution_time = 360` #360 seconds = 6 min
`max_input_time = 120`
```

[Check this link for Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552476/mysql-close-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-null-given)